# React How to refresh data of table component from HandleSubmit of one other component

Tags: reactjs, api, components

I'd like to refresh my Table component when i submit my form.

Code look like this (tell me if the structure is bad.. New in React ;) )

I don't really know how to tell to my DataProvider 
"Refresh your data, call the api again when the form is Submit !

App.JS

```
const App = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <DataProvider endpoint="api/lead/" render={data => <Table data={data} />} />
    <Form endpoint="api/lead/" />
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

DataProvider.JS

```
class DataProvider extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    endpoint: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    render: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  state = {
      data: [],
      loaded: false,
      placeholder: "Loading..."
    };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.endpoint)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          return this.setState({ placeholder: "Something went wrong" });
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data, loaded: true }));
  }

  render() {
    const { data, loaded, placeholder } = this.state;
    return loaded ? this.props.render(data) : <p>{placeholder}</p>;
  }

}
export default DataProvider;
```

Table.JS

```
const Table = ({ data }) =>
  !data.length ? (
    <p>Nothing to show</p>
  ) : (
    <div className="column">
      <h2 className="subtitle">
        Showing <strong>{data.length} items</strong>
      </h2>
      <table className="table is-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {Object.entries(data[0]).map(el => <th key={key(el)}>{el[0]}</th>)}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map(el => (
            <tr key={el.id}>
              {Object.entries(el).map(el => <td key={key(el)}>{el[1]}</td>)}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
Table.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
export default Table;
```

And at the end, there is my Form :

```
handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name, email, message } = this.state;
        const lead = { name, email, message };
        const conf = {
            method: "post",
            body: JSON.stringify(lead),
            headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
        };
        fetch(this.props.endpoint, conf).then(response => console.log(response));
    };
```

thanks